# Prove or disprove continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

If f is differentiable on an interval J in R then |f| is differentiable on J.

my answer is false.
i took a counter example. x-1 is differentiable on 1, but |x-1| is not differentiable on 1. is this correct?

Comment: The most accurate answer should be _not necessarily true_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Your answer seems right.

You can also take $f(x)=x$ which is differentiable, but $|f(x)|=|x|$ is not differentiable at $x_0=0$, since $\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{|x|}{x} \neq \lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{|x|}{x}$